# How to read input from both a file and terminal in a Python script?

Tags: python, bash, input, io-redirection

I have a Python script which reads some data from a file using shell redirection, e.g.

```
python script.py < input.txt
```

After the file is processed, I want to allow the user to enter some parameters from the terminal. How can I do this?

Comment: Using `raw_input`, `input` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: That gives `EOFError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection lasts until the process terminates. So you can't do what you want. Instead, specify your input file using a command line argument, like this:

```
python script.py --input input.txt
```

Use `argparse` to pick the name out of the command line and read it like an ordinary file. That will leave `sys.stdin` free to do the interactive things you want with `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged the question with `bash`, I think I can speak of the trick that consist of explicitely opening `/dev/tty`. This is normally only used for programs asking *secrets* that should never live in a file. But that would allow to read from the terminal even after starting a script with a redirected stdin.

Anyway, except for **very** special use case, I strongly advice to use a command line parameter instead, to allow the program to read from the specified file, and then normally read from stdin.